# Firebase getting the reference

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The full path for my reference looks like this

```
data/-KdWI6HAF0_wh9-NTEpe/films/thelobster/rating
```

and I can set it with

```
firebase.database().ref('data/-KdWI6HAF0_wh9-NTEpe/films/thelobster/rating')
  .set(5);
```

The problem is that both the keys **-KdWI6HAF0_wh9-NTEpe** and **thelobster** are dynamic.

It makes it more difficult than it should be, is there any way to build this with just the **-KdWI6HAF0_wh9-NTEpe** key and make the film name a wildcard? Oris there a better way I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase's `child()` method:

```
firebase.database().ref('data').child(key).child('films').child(filmKey).child('rating').set(5);
```

Alternatively you can use [ES6 string interpolation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals):

```
firebase.database().ref(`data/${key}/films/${filmKey}/rating`).set(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase returns '`key`' which is the id used to reference your object. Something like this.

```
var ref = firebase.database().ref("users/ada");
ref.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    var key = snapshot.key; // "ada"
    var childKey = snapshot.child("name/last").key; // "last"
  });
```

You can read more about it [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot).

For '`thelobster`', you can console.log() the data that comes from firebase, check the location of the dynamically changing 'thelobster', set it to a variable, and use the variable in your url. 
*Because I don't know how your incoming data looks like, I can't provide you with that code.*